# Facebook apps on a domain with URL forwarding and masking

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I'm developing a web application with Facebook Javascript SDK on my server at http://example.com/webapp/. Now I registered a new domain name, say domain.com, with no hosting, and I forwarded with URL masking domain.com to example.com/webapp/, so the web app is still on my server at example.com/webapp/. I've tried to change app settings on Facebook, site domain to domain.com and website URL to domain.com, but the Javascript SDK doesn't work!
I think that the problem is that requests to facebook comes from my server at example.com and the app domain is domain.com. I notice that the JS SDK uses window.location to retrieve the url to be matched with the app domain and website url.. Is there a way to inject the redirect_uri parameter on every JS SDK functions call with the url of my redirecting domain domain.com?

Thanks to all in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using URL Masking / Forwarding, you should see if you can use your domain `domain.com` pointing straight to `example.com/webapp` using `Add-on Domains`.

I.e. create a virtual host and have the new domain link to the actual files on the old domain name. Fowarding isn't the best way as some forwards use iframes or javascript to redirect.

Comment: you're right! The best way is to do what you said! However unfortunately, my hosting on `example.com` is a shared hosting so I don't know what's the IP of that domain to make `domain.com` point to it! Perhaps it has a NAT behind it? I found the IP of the server where `ecample.com` is, but not how that domain is resolved!

Comment: Ping your server and you will find the shared IP address. You should be able to use the shared IP in your DNS settings.

Comment: I did exactly what you're saying but nothing.. If I open the shared IP address in a blank browser window, the only thing I get is a void page...

Comment: Accessing the shared IP directly won't work. It will probably be something like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~your_username

Comment: I think that the only other possibility is that "routing" inside the shared server is based on some HTTP header like Host or Origin..

Comment: Best to check with your host to see how they do it. Might be easier than looking for the routing yourself. They may also be able to help you setup the domain redirection.